# Places or books to start learning PXE booting

Tags: grub, bootloader, grub2, pxe

I am currently playing around with PXE booting and PXELINUX/SYSLINUX. I have tried LTSP , thinmachine, FOG project and some others. Currently I am trying to understand how PXELINUX is working under the roof. Like looking at pxelinux.cfg and things like that. I find it all very interesting.

Are there any books on learning more on PXE booting. I was kind of looking to understand how LTSP ( as example , but more PXE booting in general) is working and able to change the behaviour, but not some simple tutorial: do this, do that..

Is there any book to learn that or where should I start or should I learn by starting with bootloaders in general (or GRUB or something).

Just to be clear, I am asking for places/books to learn more and not anything on LTSP that is not working for example.

Comment: Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with the [help center](https://superuser.com/help).  You'll see there that questions seeking learning material recommendations are off-topic here on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no books on PXE. There are no books on Syslinux. There are no books on Bootmanagers.

You can learn PXE by reading the [PXE Standard 2.1](http://www.pix.net/software/pxeboot/archive/pxespec.pdf). Syslinux can be learn from the [project page](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/The_Syslinux_Project) but the documentation is not completely updated etc.

Finally you can learn from some PXE servers like [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)
(I'm related to Serva project)